# Should small fixes to a website be a feature in git?

Tags: git, git-flow

I work for a small company and we are just implementing GIT. I'm trying to figure out what is the best practice for determining whether something is a hotfix or a feature. A lot of my time is spent fixing bugs on our website and I'm wondering if these fixes that may be under two hours of work should all be considered hotfixes.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What would happen if you decide in any way?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out the best practice for labeling something as a hotfix vs a feature.

Comment: The best solution is what works for you. Usually the feature is one big change that should be deployed in full. Hot fixes could be cherry picked and/or reversed if it does not work, while other correct fixes can go. Thus you decide.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you so much for your help. I wasn't aware that hot fixes could be reversed either.

Comment: Glad I could help. Google `cherry pick git` for more hints

Comment: The beauty of git (alongside version control) is the ability to revert to any previous commit

Comment: I would say the reply depends on your branching workflow. If you using a simple branching model with a master and short-lived branches the name hardly plays any role.